# Mongoid model that points to an AR model and vice versa?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, mongoid

Let us say we have following models in our app:

```
# AR model
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bars # this is an association pointing to a Mongoid model
end

# Mongoid model
class Bar
  include Mongoid::Document  
  belongs_to :foo # this is an association pointing to a AR model
end
```

Is it possible to create an association in a Mongoid model that points to an AR model and vice versa?

Comment: go through these it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026981/mongoid-and-activerecord-relations-undefined-method-quoted-table-name and this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090768/activerecord-and-mogoiddocument-associations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [Tenacity](https://github.com/jwood/tenacity) for this (also known as "Polyglot Persistence").  It works really well, though there are some limitations.  The owner/maintainer, JWood, is very responsive and has fixed bugs and merged in pull requests I've sent very quickly.

Comment: +1, This is what I am using now. I forgot submit my own answer.